# Why does ReadOnlySpan<T> not have an overload for Slice(...) that accepts a Range instance?

Tags: c#, .net

As I've gotten more familiar with `ReadOnlySpan<T>` and friends, I've really come to wonder why there is no overload of `Slice()` that accepts a `Range`. Specifically when one is using `ReadOnlySpan<T>.Split(...)`, one ends up with a set of `Range` instances, and from there, it is (in my opinion) clunky to turn the `Range` instances into something more useful. For example:

```cs
// make a span
var myInput = "ab,cd,ef".AsSpan();

// set up a span to hold the ranges from the Split() call
Span<Range> splitRanges = stackalloc Range[3];

// split the span based on commas
myInput.Split(splitRanges, ',');

// get the offset and length of the first range
var (offset, length) = splitRanges[0].GetOffsetAndLength(myInput.Length);

// slice the original span based on the first range's values
var firstSpan = myInput.Slice(offset, length);
```

Am I missing something? Is there a more concise, or even more idiomatic way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you can already use a `Range` to access a `ReadOnlySpan<T>` just like you would with a `Span<T>`, a string, or an array:

```
var firstSpan = myInput[splitRanges[0]];
```

It's not documented as such, because it uses the "[implicit range support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/ranges#implicit-range-support)" feature, which, in short, will turn that into a call to `Slice`. So adding a `Slice` overload that takes a `Range` would have been redundant.

Comment: Aha, yep, that's it. It was hiding in the indexer the whole time...

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own extension method for this

```
public static ReadOnlySpan<T> Slice<T>(this ReadOnlySpan<T> span, Range range)
{
    var (offset, length) = range.GetOffsetAndLength(span.Length);
    return span.Slice(offset, length);
}
```

Comment: Yes, I did that, but it doesn't answer the "why".